# Passing nil to performSelector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, null

I am using the NSObject's performSelector method to call a method based on a variable string determined at runtime.

```
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)];
```

The method call is within a loop. However, on some loop iterations I don't want to do anything and `methodName` may be nil. 
It seems that the performSelector message does not take nil as an argument. What can I do when i don't want performSelector to perform any actions?

***Edit***:
I should have been more clear. For now, i am setting `methodName = @"doNothing"` - which is what is name implies - when I want it to be nil. I want to know if there is a more elegant solution than this, or just putting an if block.
I guess my question is - **Is there a null type selector?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for this -

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)]) {
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)];
}
```

Comment: This answer is more appropriate than others as it would not crash, if `methodName` does not represents a valid method.

Answer (score 12):

Check to see if it's `nil`?

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
if (selector != nil) {
  [self performSelector:selector];
}
```

Comment: thank you. i did think of this. i've edited the question to rephrase what i meant to ask...

Comment: Dave's version is better than mine because he checks the selector rather than the method name. His code behaves gracefully if methodName is non-nil but doesn't map to a selector, whereas mine (which checks methodName != nil) throws NSInvalidArgumentException.

Comment: This code may crash ! Is not ? Consider the case when `methodName` does not represent a actual method, but is a not null string which can be converted to UTF-8. In that case `selector` will not be nil, however app will crash due to `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: So [@Tejas's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5984223/301444) is more appropriate

Answer (score 5):

```
if (methodName != nil) {
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)];
}
```

Comment: thank you. i did think of this. i've edited the question to rephrase what i meant to ask...

Comment: So you're looking for a selector name that will cause -performSelector: not to, in fact, perform a selector? The two obvious choices seem to me to be: 1) check for nil or some special name before calling -performSelector:, or 2) implement a method that does nothing and then use that method's name when you don't want anything else to happen. The first option seems the better choice, IMO, since the code will convey the meaning that you actually intend. The second choice seems sneaky and error prone, always bad things.

Comment: When you put it that way... :)

Comment: This code may crash ! Consider the case when `methodName` does not represent a actual method, but is a not null string which can be converted to UTF-8. In that case `selector` will not be nil, however app will crash due to `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. So [@Tejas's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5984223/301444) is more appropriate.